# error: request for member 'siguiente' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, estructuras, nodos

Tengo dos listas con punteros dobles.

En *listasPD.h* y *.c* cargo una lista con datos de tipo *Persona* (un nombre y una edad).

En *listasPDint.h* y *.c* cargo una lista sólo con datos de tipo int.

En ambas existe la función *retornarPrimerNodo*, escritas exactamente de la misma manera. Pero por alguna razón, en *listasPD* funciona y en *listasPDint* me dice que el miembro *siguiente* no está en una estructura.

¿Qué puede ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, muestra tanto el código como los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. Ten en cuenta que [no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes correctamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).